# Delete confirmation box not showing when i click on delete button

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 6x for my project the question is i want to show delete confirmation modal when user click on delete button. So following are my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you, want to delete?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this this the form for deleting user.

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline form-delete" action="student/'.$row->id.'">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row->id.'">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="'.Session::token().'" />
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
              <button type="submit" name="delete_modal"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

and this is jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table[data-form="deleteForm"]').on('click', '.form-delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .on('click', '#delete-btn', function() {
            $form.submit();
        });
});  });
```

Comment: remove `type="submit"` from your button.

Comment: I have removed it but still not working

Comment: make sure that your jQuery selector works. Try something like `$('.form-delete').on('click', 'button', function(e) {...`

Comment: I have another project and same this code are working in that project. I don't know why

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not able to find $('table[data-form="deleteForm"]') any where in your modal or form I think you are missing this thing here. You need to add name to your form. may be it should be name="deleteForm"

Comment: good catch @AmitSharma

Comment: there is error showing in console. Uncaught SyntacError : unexpected end of input

Comment: I have tried that too.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".form-delete").submit(function(event) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
            .on('click', '#delete-btn', function() {
                $form.submit();
            });
    });
});

Comment: request goes to controller without the confirmation

Comment: use this <button type="button" name="delete_modal"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Ok i just find the problem..  i was just missing the class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover category-table" data-toggle="dataTable" data-form="deleteForm" in the <table> tag